# Oracle - CAST(row_number) query

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT NOABSEN,TANGGAL,JAM,
        'Jam' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NOABSEN ORDER BY NOABSEN desc) as VARCHAR(20)) 
as ColumnsSequence 
From HRD_ABS_FINGER_DIVISI;
```

when the command is run appears an error like this:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
 'Jam' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(..) AS VARHCAR(20))
```

Unlike other databases (namely, SQL Server), the addition operator in Oracle really means that: addition. So as you are actually trying to add two stings, so Oracle attempts to convert them to numbers - which fails for literal string `'Jam'`.

Likely, that you want string concatenation (`||`) rather than an addition (`+`):

```
SELECT 
    NOABSEN,
    TANGGAL,
    JAM, 
    'Jam' || CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NOABSEN ORDER BY NOABSEN desc) as VARCHAR(20)) as ColumnsSequence 
From HRD_ABS_FINGER_DIVISI;
```

Comment: You don't really need the `cast()` in Oracle